# PFAddUniqueOperation - Systematic crash for a subset of users

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I released an update to my iOS app which, AFAIK, does not change the way we handle push notifications.

However, a subset of our users reports systematic crash on launch.
Fabric tells me the app crash due to :

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Operation is invalid after previous operation.
```

And shows that it's occuring when I suscribe user to default push channels in method updateAgenciesChannels :

```
NSArray *agencies = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"channelA",@"channelB", nil];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];

for(NSString *agency in agencies)
{
    NSString *agencyString = [@"a-" stringByAppendingString:agency];
    BOOL agencyState = [defaults boolForKey:agencyString];
    if(agencyState)
        [currentInstallation addUniqueObject:agencyString
                                      forKey:@"channels"];
    else
        [currentInstallation removeObject:agencyString
                                      forKey:@"channels"];

    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}
```

- It does not seems to be related to iOS version (all crashes are occuring on 9.1.3, but a lot of users on 9.1.3 are perfectly fine), nor does it seems to be related to device type.
- For this subset of users, the crash is systematic, on all launches, even after after deleting/installing the app again

Here is one of the full crash log :

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x180ffee38 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x180663f80 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x180ffed80 -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3  NextRide                       0x1001c012c -[PFAddUniqueOperation mergeWithPrevious:] (PFFieldOperation.m:277)
4  NextRide                       0x1001e1240 -[PFObject(Private) performOperation:forKey:] (PFObject.m:1172)
5  NextRide                       0x1001e83dc -[PFObject addUniqueObjectsFromArray:forKey:] (PFObject.m:2170)
6  NextRide                       0x1001e8318 -[PFObject addUniqueObject:forKey:] (PFObject.m:2166)
7  NextRide                       0x1000ac4c8 +[NRNPush updateAgenciesChannels] (NRNPush.m:54)
8  NextRide                       0x1000ac2dc +[NRNPush updateDefaultChannels] (NRNPush.m:35)
9  NextRide                       0x100083b10 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (AppDelegate.m:86)
10 UIKit                          0x1861be8a8 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:]
11 UIKit                          0x1863ee094 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:]
12 UIKit                          0x1863f2500 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:]
13 UIKit                          0x1863ef674 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:]
14 FrontBoardServices             0x18299f7ac __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
15 FrontBoardServices             0x18299f618 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext]
16 FrontBoardServices             0x18299f9c8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource]
17 CoreFoundation                 0x180fb5124 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
18 CoreFoundation                 0x180fb4bb8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
19 CoreFoundation                 0x180fb28b8 __CFRunLoopRun
20 CoreFoundation                 0x180edcd10 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
21 UIKit                          0x1861b7834 -[UIApplication _run]
22 UIKit                          0x1861b1f70 UIApplicationMain
23 NextRide                       0x1000d054c main (main.m:28)
24 libdispatch.dylib              0x180a7a8b8 (Missing)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I was potentially trying, when this method was called multiple times, to suscribe the user to a channel if he was already suscribed ("unique object" already in Array), and trying to unsuscribed the user to a channel if he was already not suscribed (remove object not in Array)